# Javascript variable not incrementing over interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, unix-timestamp

I am trying to increment a value (in this case a UNIX timestamp, but for all we care in this case it might as well be any old integer) every 1 second, but it refuses to do so (it just stays the same).

Here's the code

```
// given integer starting point
var tsmin=1332449260;
setInterval(function(){
   tsmin=tsmin++;
   console.info(ts);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from the difference between ++tsmin and tsmin++.

++tsmin increments the value before doing the next step, whereas tsmin++ increments the value afterwords. If you changed the line to:

```
tsmin = ++tsmin
```

it would work, because it is now incrementing before saving it as the new value. However, even though this solution 'works', what you really should do is:

```
tsmin++
```

There is no need to set tsmin if you are just incrementing like that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear explanation, good examples and advice on best practices to boot!

Answer (score 4):

The statement:

```
tsmin = tsmin++;
```

is guaranteed to keep "tsmin" at its same value forever. The `++` operator  **after** the variable  means that the value of that expression is the value **before** the increment. The `=` operator binds less tightly than `++`, so the process there is:

1. get the value of "tsmin"
2. increment "tsmin"
3. set "tsmin" to the value from step 1.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do tsmin++ instead of using the side affect of tsmin=tsmin++?

Answer (score 0):

```
    setInterval(function(){
   tsmin+=1;
   console.info(tsmin);
}, 1000);


setInterval(function(){
   tsmin=++tsmin;
   console.info(tsmin);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tsmin = 1332449260;
setInterval(function() {
   console.info(tsmin);
   tsmin++;
}, 1000);​
```

This assumes you want 1332449260 to be outputted in the console as the first value, if you want to start at 1332449261 move the `tsmin++;` before the `console.info(tsmin);`.